# ITIL for marketing projects

Tags: roles, subcontractor, frameworks

Is there a tailoring of ITIL for marketing projects: web, crm and mobile?

Something a marketing expert can understand who supervises the realisation of such a project by a subcontractor.

Comment: How do you mean "understand"? Is the marketing expert supposed to "audit" the subcontractors? (Formally, that's not possible.)

Comment: No, he is to manage the subcontractor to deliver the IT marketing solution.

Comment: But he is not himself an IT expert. So a full ITIL expertise is not feasible and desirable.

Comment: Then, why manage it on ITIL level? He should be able to understand requirements, user stories, performance aspects etc... I guess I'm not getting the idea here.

Answer (score 0):

### ITIL is a Service Management Framework

[ITIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITIL#Changes_and_characteristics_of_the_2011_edition_of_ITIL) is an IT *service management* framework, not a complete governance framework, and certainly **not a comprehensive project management framework or methodology**. ITIL covers:

1. ITIL Service Strategy
2. ITIL Service Design
3. ITIL Service Transition
4. ITIL Service Operation
5. ITIL Continual Service Improvement

While strategy and design sound like they're about project management because they're about aligning objectives and customer needs, it's important to remember that this is all within the context of *IT service*, rather than project management. You might spin up a project from inside an ITIL process, but ITIL itself relegates project management to sub-processes within ITIL Service Transition, with a [focus on coordination and conflict resolution within ITIL](https://wiki.en.it-processmaps.com/index.php/Project_Management_-_Transition_Planning_and_Support#Process_Description).

> In ITIL 2011 Project Management has been revised to highlight that its main responsibility is to coordinate the various service transition projects and resolve conflicts...Projects are initiated when Service Portfolio Management has chartered a new or substantially changed service.

A better way to look at your use case is that **you have an IT project to support a marketing initiative**. Select a service management framework to plan and operate your IT solutions, and a project management framework to build and deliver the solution within any governance, compliance, security, and service management frameworks that may apply.